# AWS ELB causing net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-elb

Currently getting the `net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` when trying to access my application through the ALB.

This is my current setup:

- SSL Certificate created that covers `example.com` & `*.example.com` using AWS Certificate Manager.
- 2 server ec2 instances behind a load balancer and 2 client instances behind another load balancer.
- An alias record in my Route 53 hosted zone pointing to the client ALB.
- Both ALBs have the SSL certificate for `example.com` attached to them.
- Both ALBs have a single `HTTPS: 443` listener forwarding `https` traffic to ec2 instances on port 80.
- The server ALB security group allows inbound traffic from the client ALB Security Group and outbound to the server instances security group.
- The applications in the client ec2 instances are React Apps pointing to the server ALB at `https://xxxxxxxxxx.elb.amazonaws.com/api`

Accessing the application via `https://example.com` causes `net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` in the console with the browser saying:

> Error: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “xxxxxxxxxx.elb.amazonaws.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.

I'd be happy to provide more details if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your own domain `example.com` with correct SSL certificate then you can't use `https://xxxxxxxxxx.elb.amazonaws.com/api` which is AWS domain. The reason is that SSL cert is for `example.com`, not for `https://xxxxxxxxxx.elb.amazonaws.com/api`.

You have to modify your application code to only use `example.com`.

Comment: What SSL certs should I then associated with the ALBs? Since ```example.com``` is pointing to the Load Balancer for the client apps, if I changed the application code to use ```example.com/api/``` that would still point to the client app. How could I point to the servers behind their own load balancer while still using ```example.com``` ?

Comment: @AnthonyMaina I don't understand. Everything from your front-end has to go through ALB using example.com, that's why you have it in the first place.

Comment: Got it. I created a new record on route 53 called ```api.example.com``` pointing to the server ALB. Now the application code uses that to communicate to the servers and it's working now with no errors.